# Embed in navigation controller by code in appDelegate.m instead of "Menu:Editor --> embed in --> navigation controller"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create tabbar controller by code in appDelegate.m and set tabbar controller is rootViewController.So,In the main.storyboard I don't have a pointer to navigation controller,I would like to set navigation controller for tabbarcontronller by code,how can I do this?
If I don't set navigation controller,It will throw exception that "'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"

```
NSArray *titleList = @[@"Bán chạy",@"Mới nhất",@"Lịch sử",@"Khách hàng"];
    NSArray *imageList = @[@"icon_hot_normal.png",@"icon_new_normal.png",@"icon_history_normal.png",@"icon_user_normal.png"];

    NSArray *viewCtrIdentifierList = @[@"best_sale_id",@"history_id"];

    UITabBarController *tabbarCtr = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarCtr;
    [tabbarCtr navigationController];
    NSMutableArray *tabbarList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i < viewCtrIdentifierList.count; i++) {
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewCtr = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewCtrIdentifierList[i]];
        [tabbarList addObject:viewCtr];
    }

    tabbarCtr.viewControllers = tabbarList;
    int i=0;
    for (UITabBarItem *item in tabbarCtr.tabBar.items) {
        item.title = titleList[i];
        item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageList[i]];
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should be what you need to get on the right track.

Basically, you need to wrap each tab's root view controller in a `UINavigationController`. You were very close.

This code should fix your problem:

```
NSArray *viewCtrIdentifierList  = @[@"best_sale_id",@"history_id"];
UITabBarController *tabbarCtr   = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController  = tabbarCtr;
NSMutableArray *tabbarList      = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i < viewCtrIdentifierList.count; i++) {
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard    = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewCtr   = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewCtrIdentifierList[i]];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewCtr];
    [tabbarList addObject:nav];
}
tabbarCtr.viewControllers = tabbarList;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply my question!It's really smooth run.So greate!Thank you again!